# File Moving Problem?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

I want to move the files to another folder.

Code.

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
fso.MoveFile (txtsourcedatabasefile & "\" & "1.txt"), App.Path & "\Uploaded\"
```

txtsourcedatabasefile = "C:"

Above code is not working, it showing error as object variable or with block variable not set.

How to modify my code.

Need VB6 code Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fso` is not initialized to anything, try replacing

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
```

with:

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of questions:

1. What is `fso` set to?
2. What is `txtsourcedatabasefile` set to?

That is, I suspect, where your problem lies. I'd be looking at `fso` myself to make sure you've set it.

*Update:*

In your question updates, your code:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
```

creates the object but you don't actually initialize it to anything. You need to do:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
```

This is actually preferable in the vast majority of the cases since the near-equivalent:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
```

creates an auto-instantiating object, meaning every time you use it, it will check to see if it needs to be created.

That makes a code segment like:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
fso.DoThis()
fso.DoThat()
if fso.EverythingDone then
    fso.Shutdown()
end if
```

expensive since it will check `fso` four times to see if it exists (and create it only the first time). It's more efficient to create it manually once.

Comment: I modify my question, Check now